# What is the best parctice for debugging production javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript SPA app, based on React, that it is about to go live.

In the app itself I log all Javascript exceptions and save them on the server for further debugging.

As my app will be minified I was wondering how I am to debug the stack traces I will get when a bug is hit.

I came across [stacktracejs](https://www.stacktracejs.com) which looks promising, but the documentation looks a bit thin. So I was wondering if there is something better out there.

---

Just to clarify, coming from C world myself, I am essentially asking what is the equivalent to "GDB", where I can load the core a binary on it and start debugging.

Comment: Your minifier should be configurable to produce a *source map*.

Comment: Yes, I have the source map, but not sure how I can combine the source map and the traceback that I will get form the user to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like [source-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map) (If you can run nodejs on your server).

There you would load your source-map for the given file:

```
 var smc = new SourceMapConsumer(rawSourceMap);
```

Then you would need to parse your stack trace extracting all line and column numbers. Those information you then can use to retrieve the original position.

```
console.log(smc.originalPositionFor({
  line: 1,
  column: 2
}));
```

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks. No tool that will do that for me then? Sorry, coming from C world, I was expecting I would be able to load my "core" and binary to gdb and see what's going on. Nothing equivalent to that?

Comment: @599644  [sourcemapped-stacktrace](https://github.com/novocaine/sourcemapped-stacktrace) might work for you, it internally uses `source-map`, but I never took a look on it.